# Get NS and MX web information python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to get information about two domain input with this code:

```
#! usr/bin/python
domainlist=[]
#Ask for domain 1
domain = raw_input("------------------------------------------\nIntroduce el primer domino de la pagina web:\n")
domainlist.append(domain)
#Ask for domain 2
domain = raw_input("------------------------------------------\nIntroduce el segundo domino de la pagina web:\n")
domainlist.append(domain)
print "-------------------"

#Declare Variable
#Find dns
def fundns():
    import dns.resolver
    idns = dns.resolver.query(i,'NS')
    print "Los DNS de %s" % domain + " son:"
    for server in idns:
        print server 
#Find mx
def funmx():        
    import dns.resolver
    mx = dns.resolver.query(i,'MX')
    print "Los MX de %s" % domain + " son:"
    for rdata in mx:
        print "Host", rdata.exchange
for i in domainlist:
    fundns()
    print "----------------------------------------"
    funmx()
```

but I received this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ejercicio5.py", line 29, in
>   
>       funmx()   File "ejercicio5.py", line 22, in funmx

I can see in the print all the information unless last `mx` registry, and I don't know what is wrong...

Some one could help me?

Comment: Is it whole error section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually pass the domain names to your functions

```
import dns.resolver

domainlist = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com']

#Declare Variable
#Find dns
def fundns(domain):

    idns = dns.resolver.query(domain,'NS')
    print "Los DNS de %s" % domain + " son:"
    for server in idns:
        print server 
#Find mx
def funmx(domain):        

    mx = dns.resolver.query(domain,'MX')
    print "Los MX de %s" % domain + " son:"
    for rdata in mx:
        print "Host", rdata.exchange

for i in domainlist:
    fundns(i)
    print "----------------------------------------"
    funmx(i)
```

Previously you were trying to use global variables, or so it seems.

The Output:

```
Los DNS de google.com son:
ns3.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
----------------------------------------
Los MX de google.com son:
Host alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
Host alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
Host alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
Host alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
Host aspmx.l.google.com.
Los DNS de yahoo.com son:
ns6.yahoo.com.
ns2.yahoo.com.
ns5.yahoo.com.
ns3.yahoo.com.
ns1.yahoo.com.
ns4.yahoo.com.
----------------------------------------
Los MX de yahoo.com son:
Host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
Host mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
Host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
```

Comment: Hi @paulrooney thanks for your answer, my code seems works fine, i was writing a domain without mx registry and appears this error. Your code works good also but i want to ask for domain. My question know is, how can i control if the answers of dns.resolver don't give me a mx registry for avoid an error?

Comment: Hi sorry. I don't really understand your second question. Perhaps it would be better to create a new question for this.